# How do I escape an underscore that follows a macro name?

Tags: sas

I'm writing some `proc sql` code like this

```
%let psample = 10;
proc sql;
    create table mylib.matches_&psample_some_suffix as
    select ...
```

but SAS gives me the warning

```
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference PSAMPLE_SOME_SUFFIX not resolved.
```

How do I make SAS understand that the macro name stops with `psample` and not `psample_some_suffix'? For readability, I want these underscores in my file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dot to explicitly end the macro variable reference:

```
mylib.matches_&psample._some_suffix
```